# Unit Testing a KafkaListenerErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a test listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = TEST_TOPIC)
public void consume(
        ConsumerRecord<String, Map> consumerRecord,
        @Payload String message) {
}
```

And a test producer:

```
@Test
public void throwExceptionTest() throws Exception {
    Exception kafkaException = new Exception("test exception");
    kafkaTemplate.send(TEST_TOPIC, "testKey", kafkaException);
}
```

And I am trying to unit test the Kafka Listener Error handler:

```
@Component
@FunctionalInterface
public interface KafkaListenerErrorHandler {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaListenerErrorHandler.class);


/**
 * Handle the error.
 * @param message the spring-messaging message.
 * @param exception the exception the listener threw, wrapped in a
 * {@link ListenerExecutionFailedException}.
 * @return the return value is ignored unless the annotated method has a
 * {@code @SendTo} annotation.
 */
Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception);

/**
 * Handle the error.
 * @param message the spring-messaging message.
 * @param exception the exception the listener threw, wrapped in a
 * {@link ListenerExecutionFailedException}.
 * @param consumer the consumer.
 * @return the return value is ignored unless the annotated method has a
 * {@code @SendTo} annotation.
 */
default Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception,
                           Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    logger.info(String.format("KafkaListenerErrorHandler:%s", exception.getMessage()));
    return handleError(message, exception);
}
```

}

Having trouble figuring out how to throw an error on purpose that would trigger that handler.

Any help would be appreciated.